# Undo unfollow people in Facebook

Tags: facebook

I have seen a post in Facebook, I clicked on **Hide** > **Change what update you get from UserXXX** > **Unfollow**

Now I want to undo this and see again the post of UserXXX in my Wall.

I have tried to google for it but I can't find a solution.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.facebook.com/help/335291769884272/:

To unhide stories from people, Pages or app at a later time:

1. From your home page, hover over News Feed in the left sidebar menu.
2. Click the pencil icon that appears to the left and select Edit Settings.
3. A list of people, apps, Pages and groups you’ve hidden or unfollowed from will appear in a pop-up window. Click X next to each one you'd like to remove from this list. Removing someone or something from your list of hidden stories means those stories can appear in your News Feed again.
4. Click Save.

[image]

Comment: it is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

As of 5/31/2014, it's pretty simple. but keep it mind that Facebook tends to change their UI pretty frequently.

Simply go to the person's page and along with his/her name you see 4 clickable menus on the right side. "friends, following, message, ..." you just click on the "following or follow" button to change the persons status on your newsfeed.